# JavaFX ComboBox auto fills editor text when using arrow keys

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm looking to make an auto complete combo box in javafx by using a combo box. I have it being able to filter items, but one of the issues I'm having is that if the user uses the arrow keys to go through the filtered list, the combo box editor gets populated with that item, even if they actually don't want to select that item. Does anyone know how to disable this functionality from a combo box or will I have to make my own custom component.

Here's what I have so far.

```
public abstract class AutoComplete<T> extends ComboBox<T> {

public AutoComplete() {
    setEditable(true);
    getEditor().setOnKeyReleased(this::handleKeyPressed);
}
private void handleKeyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
    event.consume();
    if (event.getCode().isArrowKey()) {
            moveCaretToEnd();
            show();
    } else if (event.getCode().isLetterKey() && !event.isControlDown()) {
        moveCaretToEnd();
        show();
        handleTextInputChanged();
    } else if (getItems().size() == 0) {
        hide();
    } else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
        hide();
    } else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.BACK_SPACE) {
        show();
        handleTextInputChanged();
    }
}

private void moveCaretToEnd(){
    getEditor().positionCaret(getText().length());
}

protected void handleTextInputChanged(){

}

protected abstract String display(T item);
}
```

Any help in disabling this functionality in combo box would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that when an item is selected in Combo boxes, the combo box has a default StringConverter which calls T.toString() when the selection model changes.

The *workaround is to set your own StringConverter like so.

```
public AutoComplete() {
    setConverter(new StringConverter<T>(){
        @Override
        public String toString(T item) {
            return item == null ? null : display(item);
        }
        @Override
        public T fromString(String string) {
            return getFromString(string);
        }
    });
}

protected abstract T getFromString(String input);

protected abstract String display(T item);
```

*I say workaround because this is probably not the best / most efficient way if your auto complete is getting data from the server on every key stroke. But for me, this solves the issue of the editor calling my object's to string method whenever selecting an item in the combo box list.